# Problem with Samba + NetBIOS. Can't ping Ubuntu from Windows

Tags: networking, windows, samba, ping

I cannot ping my Ubuntu box from Windows. I have Samba installed and I have checked iptables and NetBIOS ports are not blocked. smbd and nmbd are both running.

I'm running Ubuntu 11.10 Server. I was able to set this up fine and getting working on my Ubuntu 11.10 Desktop.

I've looked at several other posts, but none of them fix my problem. Any ideas?

Comment: The computers are on the same subnet.

Comment: the computers are connected through a standard gigabit switch. They are still on the same subnet, but would this prevent broadcast packets from being forwarded?

Comment: In what way does it not work, what error do you get?

Comment: Ping request could not find host my_hostname. Please check the name and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu doesn't support looking up hosts by NetBIOS name using NSS. In other words, you can't do `ping netbiosname` except if you use nss_wins.

If you have a WINS server you can set up nss_wins and use that to resolve NetBIOS names.

Alternatively, you can use something like Avahi or DNS.

Comment: Samba includes NetBIOS. Install Samba, get NetBIOS. The service is called nmbd. It works on my Ubuntu desktop. I can ping it from other machines on the same subnet. For some reason it's not working with the two Ubuntu server machines I setup.

Comment: I would be willing to go the WINS route, but the machines are connected to a network with Active Directory. So they can't be added to the DNS there. And the WINS server can't be on the Ubuntu machines because they have dynamic IPs.

Comment: nmbd in Samba does server-side NetBIOS support and browsing; it doesn't integrate into the NSS host name look ups that are part of libc.

Comment: If you have Active Directory then I doubt NetBIOS would work at all - instead, you probably just want to use the DNS server from the AD domain.

Comment: Cant use the AD. This works on an Ubuntu desktop installation on the same subnet. I'm starting to wonder if this has something to do with broadcast packets not being forwarded through the switch.

Comment: That shouldn't matter - Samba doesn't add the ability to do "ping netbiosname" except when you explicitly set up nss_wins to look up the netbiosname via WINS.

Comment: What is nmbd then? I'm really confused.

Comment: nmbd manages browsing, WINS and the NetBIOS name of your local machine. You can use the 'nmblookup' utility to look up an IP from a NetBIOS name.

Answer (score 0):

If your ubuntu server has a fixed IP address, you can try to put the address in hosts file on windows machines.  I never figured out how NetBIOS work.  So I just use fixed IP + hosts files in my LAN.

Comment: DHCP and dynamic IPs. I definitely don't want to use hosts file.